# RegEx to extract only selectors from CSS file?

Tags: c#, css, regex, css-selectors

I'm trying to find a regular expression that will let me extract *JUST* the rules from a CSS file. I don't want any of the style declarations, simply the rules (selectors). Here's the sample CSS file I'm working with:

```
body, p, table, td, th, br, div, span {
    /* Some styles here */
}

/* This is a test */
h1 {
    /* Some styles here */
}

a:hover {
    /* Some styles here */
}

-moz-any(input[type="text"], input[type="radio"]) {
    /* Some styles here */
}
```

In this example I would expect my regular expression to match the following items: body, p, table, td, th, br, div, span, h1, a:hover, -moz-any(input[type="text"], input[type="radio"])

Here's my attempt at the regular expression. While it works, it includes the /* This is a test */ comment and it also includes the curly braces. Ideally those would be omitted.

```
(}{0,})([^}]*)({)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

I should also note that I understand this isn't a great CSS file. It's simply a test file I came up with to test my parsing with.

Comment: To do this with regex is complicated, you are better off using a proper parser.

Comment: Four things: 1) Rules and selectors are *not* the same thing. You're looking for just the selectors. 2) `:-moz-any()` is a pseudo-class, as such it requires the `:` before it. 3) What language are you implementing the regular expression in? If it's a JavaScript regex, there are existing questions which you can search this site for with the relevant terms. 4) You're probably not going to get very far with a regex once you work with more complex stylesheets.

Comment: Bolt - I understand my terminology may be incorrect. I am by no means a CSS expert. I did not know the -moz-any required a : before it, whoops. Either way, the point remains that I would like to grab that. Also, I'm implementing this in C#.

Qtax - What would make the RegEx to do this complicated? My RegEx-Foo is really bad :)

Comment: I've added the appropriate tags. There are a number of complicating factors, but @ rules, which may or may not nest, are the usual suspect (e.g. media queries).

Comment: Thank you for modifying the tags, Bolt. I've also updated the title so it is correct. I'm actually not too concerned with media queries or @keyframes (or any @ selectors, really). What I'm trying to do, essentially, is take in a CSS file and generate an HTML file that shows examples of all the styles defined in it. Yes, I understand there are issues with this I need to solve (i.e, what do you generate as an example for a .class which is not very specific?).

Comment: Is the file always the same format?  Will rules always be indented with tabs, and selectors have the bracket on the same line of declaration?

Comment: You would need to parse all CSS language constructs to get it right, like comments, quotes, etc. That's making a full parser for CSS with regex. It could be done with a complicated expression (and some code on the side), but that is what parsers are for. I'm sure there are C# parsers for CSS, so there is no need to reinvent the wheel, unless this is just an exercise.

Comment: Qtax - The problem with a full parser is they typically return way more information than I need. Also, this is kind of a learning experience for me :) Dave, the format will NOT be the same for every file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get a solution using RegEx, so I followed Qtax's advice and used a proper parser with CSS3 grammar.

I am marking this question as the answer.

@Qtax - If you add your comment as an answer, I'll mark that as the "correct" answer :)

Comment: did you define the CSS3 grammar?  What was your choice as a proper parser?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you always have the opening squggley-bracket on the same line as your declaration, as in your example:

```
(.+) {
```

I can give you some code that shows how to get the group if you need it. Let me know what language you're using and I'll try and comply!

Answer (score 0):

This crude regex will catch selectors in sub pattern 2. Since it is not a parser, it will also catch selectors in comments, though.

```
(\s|^)(.*?)\s*{
```